# When scrolling over my footer, the scroll stops

Tags: html, css, reactjs, scroll

So I have a react next js application, the issue I have seems to be related to my footer. I just noticed that when I scroll on one specific page, there seems to be an issue with how the window "moves". I'm on the page and I start scrolling down, It all works fine until the footer should start being visible. As soon as it should be visible: it stops scrolling *I'm continuasly scrolling at the same pace* (its like it halts teh scroll and then keeps going), the footer eventually does start to show. When I scroll up, the footer instead "stays sticky in the bottom" until I reach *almost the top of the page* (it feels like this is exactly where the space from the footer would *reach the top* if it was at the top instead of the bottom. Then if I keep scrolling, eventually it does move.

I cannot figure out what is wrong, its just in one page that this issue is so some combo of css must be causing issues in the page.

Footer:

```
        <footer className=" w-full  p-8">
            <div className="w-10/12 mx-auto py-4">
                <div className="flex">
                    <svg
                        width="77"
                        height="25"
                        viewBox="0 0 77 25"
                        fill="none"
                        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                    >
                       
                    </svg>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="grid lg:grid-cols-2 w-10/12 mx-auto py-4">
                <div>
                    <h4 className="text-4xl text-mb-4 font-FooterText font-semibold">
                     
                    </h4>
                    <form className="w-[90%] py-4 flex" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                        <input
                            type="email"
                            className="p-2 w-3/4 bg-transparent font-montserrat border rounded-l-lg border-white placeholder-white text-white"
                            placeholder="Enter Your Email"
                            name="emailId"
                            onChange={(event) => setEmailID(event.target.value)}
                            value={emailID}
                            required
                        />
                        <button
                            className="w-1/4 font-montserrat text-xs font-bold border rounded-r-lg bg-white border-white text-black">
                            SUBSCRIBE
                        </button>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div className="grid lg:grid-cols-3 lg:justify-items-center">
                    {renderFooterMenu}
                </div>
            </div>
            {showModal ? (
                <>
                    <div
                        className="justify-center items-center flex overflow-x-hidden overflow-y-auto fixed inset-0 z-50 outline-none focus:outline-none">
                        <div className="relative w-auto my-auto mx-auto">
                            <div
                                className="border-0 rounded-lg shadow-lg relative flex flex-col w-full bg-white outline-none focus:outline-none">
                                <button
                                    className="p-4 text-red-700 place-content-end flex"
                                    onClick={() => setShowModal(false)}
                                >
                                    <svg
                                        className="h-6 w-6 fill-current"
                                        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                                        viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                                    >
                                        <path
                                            fillRule="evenodd"
                                            d="M12.7 10l6.65-6.65a1 1 0 1 0-1.42-1.42L11.3 8.58 4.65 1.93a1 1 0 1 0-1.42 1.42L8.58 10l-6.35 6.35a1 1 0 1 0 1.42 1.42L10 11.42l6.65 6.65a1 1 0 1 0 1.42-1.42L12.7 10z"
                                            clipRule="evenodd"
                                        />
                                    </svg>
                                    {/*Close*/}
                                </button>
                                <Terms />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="opacity-25 fixed inset-0 z-40 bg-black"></div>
                </>
            ) : null}
        </footer>
```